# how to connect 4 devices for bidirectional communication using sockets in python

Tags: python, sockets, network-programming, python-3.7

I'm setting up connection between 4 devices(A,B,C & D) such that all can send messages to each other using sockets.

I have tried using client/server idea. I made device A a client since it will be initiating the connection and made others both server and client simultaneously(so that they can send messages back and forth). I feel the code for B, C and D should be similar since they basically do same thing. I used same port between A&B, another between B&C...
I can send message A to B, then B to c, and C to D but cannot send back messages in the reverse direction

```
Device A code
*************
import socket
import time
host = socket.gethostname()
port = 8088
s = socket.socket()
s.connect((host, port))
print('Calling...')
time.sleep(2)
ms1_message = input(str('A_State>>'))
while A_message != str('bye'):
    s.send(A_message.encode())
    B_message = s.recv(30)
    B_message = B_message.decode()
    print('B sends:>> ', B_message)
```

```
Device B code
********
import socket
import time
import sys
from _thread import *

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = socket.gethostname()
port = 8088

try:
    s.bind((host, port))
except socket.error:
    print('Binding Failed!!!')
    sys.exit()
s.listen(4)
print('Listening for connections...')
A, addr = s.accept()
print('A connected')
while True:
    recv_message_ms1 = A.recv(30)
    if not recv_message_A:
        break
    print('A sends:>> ', recv_message_A.decode())

    message = 'ACK'
    message = message.encode()
    A.send(message)
    time.sleep(3)
    print('Searching for C...')
    # connection setup to C
    s2 = socket.socket()
    port2 = 8089
    C = socket.gethostname()
    s2.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    s2.connect((C, port2))
    print('...Connected with C')
    B_message = 'Channel Setup Request...'.encode()
    # B_message = B_message.encode()
    s2.send(B_message)
```

I am expecting a result like A send message to B, B confirms the message with and ACK back to A and B sends another message to C, C sends back ACK and sends messages to D, D sends back ACK and the reverse messages happen.
can anyone guide me on what to do?
NB: Python only